# Query to return the hour with most actions

Tags: c#, linq

I am runing a query to find the "best hour",best hour = hour with the most orders.
i try:

```
   public void ShowBestHour()
    {
        using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            var query=
                from z in db.Order_Details
                select new
                {
                    bestHour = z.Order.OrderDate.Value.Hour.Count()
                }; 
        }
    }
```

how should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void ShowBestHour()
{
    using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
    {            
        var bestHour = db.Order_Details.GroupBy(x => x.Order.OrderDate.Value.Hour).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Key).First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution should be using the **let** clause will help.

So group by count, define a variable with let on the count, then order on this variabel.
This question was similar to yours:

[How to get the Max() of a Count() with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200126/how-to-get-the-max-of-a-count-with-linq)